# MongoDB queries in Lithium - should I use `order` or `$orderby`, or doesn't it matter?

Tags: performance, mongodb, lithium

The following two criteria sets give me identical results using Lithium and MongoDB. Both are equally easy to read and write. Should I prefer one over the other for efficiency reasons, or is one just Lithium/MongoDB syntactic sugar for the other?

```
$criteria = array(
    'fields' => array('_id', 'title', 'created', 'edited', 'username'),
    'order' => {'edited' => 'ASC'},
    'limit' => 3
);
```

And

```
$criteria = array(
    '$orderby' => array('edited' => 'ASC'),
    'fields' => array('_id', 'title', 'created', 'edited', 'username'),
    'limit' => 3
);
```

---

Follow up question: I really struggled to figure out the right syntax to use for `order` and `$orderby`, and in general I find Lithium's code pretty hard to grok. Do you have any suggestions on how best to approach the codebase for better/faster understanding?

PS: I realise the follow up question might not really be StackOverflow style - but there are other posts on SO and elsewhere which hint at exactly this problem (e.g. [Lithium apps that go beyond CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667741/lithium-apps-that-go-beyond-crud)). Any input on this could be really valuable!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lithium translate `'order'` to a MongoBD `sort()` *[source](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/source/MongoDb.php#L477)*

MongoDB's `$orderby` directive is equivalent to calling `sort()` after a `find()` *[source](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24orderby)*

So both are equivalent.
I'll go with `order` since it's a consistent and unified API to interact with any underlying datasource.

Hope it helps